# Multiline equations within parentheses

Tags: spacing, align

I have two equations which need to be broken into multiple lines. One of the equations has a coeficiente factored out, so that it is of the form X = A(...very long...). The other does not.

The equations were written as

```
$\!\begin{aligned} 
    y &= \frac{1}{A}\left(\frac{b_1\cdot{}t_{f1}^2}{2}+h_w\cdot{}t_w\left(t_{f1}+\frac{h_w}{2}\right)+\right.\\
    &\phantom{=}\left.+b_2\cdot{}t_{f2}\left(t_{f1}+h_w+\frac{t_{f2}}{2}\right)\right)\\
    I_y &= \dfrac{1}{12}\left(b_1\cdot{}t_{f1}^3+t_w\cdot{}h_w^3+b_2\cdot{}t_{f2}^3\right)+\\
    &\phantom{=}+b_1\cdot{}t_{f1}\left(y-\dfrac{t_{f1}}{2}\right)^2+\\
\end{aligned}$
```

The use of `$\!\begin{aligned}` instead of a standard `align` environment is because this is contained within a table. This results in the following output:
[image: Equations]

This is fine and is as expected. However, the global parentheses in the first equation required the use of `\right.` and `\left.` at the end of the first line and beginning of the second line, which seems to eat the space between the `+` and `b`, as becomes clear when you compare the space between them in the first and second equations.

This is a purely aesthetic issue, but I'm curious to know if it is (preferably trivially) solved.

Comment: Move `\left.` to the left of `\phantom`.

Comment: Well, don't I feel like a fool now! >.>

Comment: Actually, I think this can be refined, so no `\phantom` needed at all, but I haven't managed to do this yet.